# How to track visitors

Tags: hyperlink

Suppose that we have a website with info about 10 products. Next to each product there is hidden hyperlink "More info" to the product page in the seller web and one direct link to the sellers web. We get revenue from unique visits. So our task is to track how many visitors (unique and all) clicked on those links. Also we need to have such info of daily/monthly/yearly timescale.

**What is more - those sellers in their GA should see the same unique/all numbers as we do!**

What is the best way to track such information?

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Analytics: http://www.google.com/analytics/ or AWSTAT: http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

you should have table for these records like "STATISTICS" as table name where

ID (primary key ) (auto increment) 
CategoryofProduct (if you wanna sort by category)
ProductID 
VisitorID (save IP Address of the visiter)
VisitedTimes
VisitedDate

when inserting a new row (at process out) into the table please check if any duplicate visitor (IP address) exist for the particular product if does , the just update the "VisitedTimes" by one else insert new row , hope it will work for you